# Cannot stop loading if url iframe offline or not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How to stop the spinner when url is offline and display a warning that the offline or not found url??

**CSS**

```
#loadImg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
#loadImg div {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #fff;
    height: 633px;        
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 2000px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="loadImg">
    <div>
        <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9XwrYMe59OY/WOBFFeppEYI/AAAAAAAAB2A/CtyK_-GN8DUMzJypSJqnLKEDn4f-5_fOwCLcB/s320/balls.gif" />
    </div>
</div>

<iframe width="100%" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';" frameborder="0" height="1000px" class="col-sm-12" src="https://testmyweb.com/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

A method to do this is to create a page which sends a request to the target and displays its response. If there was no response, then handle the error. Your new proxy page will be used as the target inside your `iframe`, but you will need to make sure you handle the relative URLs of the target page, that is, you rewrite those URLs to absolute paths. You will need to take a look at the `src` attribute of `img` and `script` tags and you will also need to take a look at the `href` of `a` and `link` tags. In case a CSS rule uses `url()` with a relative path, you will need to write your own CSS which overrides those rules.